# RSpec gives: "f" is not a number for `rgba'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've just changed views and layouts in my rails app and tried to run tests.
RSpec gives me a little wired message:

> Failure/Error: visit '/pages/contact'
>
> ```
>  ActionView::Template::Error:
>    $red: "f" is not a number for `rgba'
>      (in */app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
> ```

I tried googling but there're not results.

What does mean this message?

My manifest file:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require styles.css
```

And in `style.css` there are lines like `color:#ffffff;`. But could it be a problem?

Tests are very simple:

```
  describe "Contact page" do
    it "shold have the content 'Contact'" do
      visit contact_path
      expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
    end
    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
      visit contact_path
      expect(page).to have_title(title + ' | Contact')
    end
```

And my view file:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Contact') %>
<h1>Contact</h1>
```

When I do manual tests everything is OK and looks good.

Comment: Hard to tell what the problem is without more code. You should at least post the code for the failed test and the ofending view `pages/contact`

Comment: I add test code and view's code. And before changing in layouts tests were green.

Comment: Do you happen to have any line like this in any of you css files? `rgba( ... )`. The proper format of those lines should be `rgba(<integer>,<integer>,<integer>,<real>)`. Maybe an hex color string `fff` slipped in instead of the numbers.

Comment: Yes, I have `-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(f,f,f,0.1);`. So how could I transform it? Hex F is 15 dec but what could I do with it...

Comment: Try `-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);`